# pandas change list of value into column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like this and I want to change the list of value into column

```

````
    uid   device
0   000 [1.0, 3.0]
1   001 [3.0]
2   003 [nan]
3   004 [2.0, 3.0]
4   005 [1.0]
5   006 [1.0]
6   006 [nan]
7   007 [2.0]
```
````

should be

```

```
    uid  device      NA  just_1  just_2or3  Both
0   000 [1.0, 3.0]   0     0         0        1
1   001 [3.0]        0     0         1        0
2   003 [nan]        1     0         0        0
3   004 [2.0, 3.0]   0     0        "1"       0
4   005 [1.0]        0     1         0        0
5   006 [1.0]        0     1         0        0
6   006 [nan]        1     0         0        0
7   007 [2.0]        0     1         1        0
8   008 [1.0, 2.0]   0     0         0        1
```

```

I want to change to dummy variable, if device only 1.0, set corresponding column value = 1, if 2.0, 3.0, [2.0,3.0]，set just_2or3 = 1.

Only if 1.0 in list, like [1.0,3.0],[1.0,2.0]，set both = 1

How can I do that?
thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use custom function `f` with list comprehensions, last cast `boolean` values to `int` by [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'uid':['000','001','002','003','004','005','006','007'],
                   'device':[[1.0,3.0],[3.0],[np.nan],[2.0,3.0],
                             [1.0],[1.0],[np.nan],[2.0]]})

print (df)
       device  uid
0  [1.0, 3.0]  000
1       [3.0]  001
2       [nan]  002
3  [2.0, 3.0]  003
4       [1.0]  004
5       [1.0]  005
6       [nan]  006
7       [2.0]  007

def f(x):
    #print (x)
    NA = [np.nan in x][0]
    just_1  = [1 in x and not(2 in x or 3 in x)][0]
    both = [1 in x and (2 in x or 3 in x)][0]
    just_2or3 = [1 not in x and (2 in x or 3 in x)][0]
    return pd.Series([NA, just_1, just_2or3, both], 
                     index=['NA','just_1','just_2or3', 'both'])

print (df.set_index('uid').device.apply(f).astype(int).reset_index())
   uid  NA  just_1  just_2or3  both
0  000   0       0          0     1
1  001   0       0          1     0
2  002   1       0          0     0
3  003   0       0          1     0
4  004   0       1          0     0
5  005   0       1          0     0
6  006   1       0          0     0
7  007   0       0          1     0
```

Comment: nice one, I completely forgot about `astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

You can create such columns by expressing the conditions as booleans and converting those to `int`, all wrapped in list comprehension:

```
df['just_1'] = [int(1 in x and not(2 in x or 3 in x)) for x in df.device]
```

and

```
df['both'] = [int(1 in x and (2 in x or 3 in x)) for x in df.device]
```

and

```
df['just_2or3'] = [int(1 not in x and (2 in x or 3 in x)) for x in df.device]
```

and

```
df['NA'] = [int(np.nan in x) for x in df.device]
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom function with [`pandas.DataFrame.apply`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) and [`pandas.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.get_dummies.html) function:

```
def worker(x):
    ch1 = 1 in x
    ch23 = any(i in x for i in [2,3])
    if ch1 and ch23:
        return 'both'
    elif ch1:
        return 'just_1'
    elif ch23:
        return 'just_2or3'
    else:
        return 'NA'

>>> res = pd.get_dummies(df.device.apply(worker))
>>> res
   NA  both  just_1  just_2or3
0   0     1       0          0
1   0     0       0          1
2   1     0       0          0
3   0     0       0          1
4   0     0       1          0
5   0     0       1          0
6   1     0       0          0
7   0     0       0          1
```

**old answer**

```
def worker(x):
    ch1 = 1 in x
    ch23 = any(i in x for i in [2,3])
    if ch1 and ch23:
        return {'both':1}
    elif ch1:
        return {'just_1':1}
    elif ch23:
        return {'just_2or3':1}
    else:
        return {'NA':1}

>>> res = df.device.apply(worker).apply(pd.Series).fillna(0).astype(int)
>>> res
   NA  both  just_1  just_2or3
0   0     1       0          0
1   0     0       0          1
2   1     0       0          0
3   0     0       0          1
4   0     0       1          0
5   0     0       1          0
6   1     0       0          0
7   0     0       0          1
```

if you need merged dataset:

```
>>> pd.concat([df, res], axis=1)
       device  uid  NA  both  just_1  just_2or3
0  [1.0, 3.0]  000   0     1       0          0
1       [3.0]  001   0     0       0          1
2       [nan]  002   1     0       0          0
3  [2.0, 3.0]  003   0     0       0          1
4       [1.0]  004   0     0       1          0
5       [1.0]  005   0     0       1          0
6       [nan]  006   1     0       0          0
7       [2.0]  007   0     0       0          1
```